# eUML & Eclipse Kepler: Has someone been able to make it work?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, tool-uml

I'm trying to install eUML2 on my Eclipse Kepler installation.

So far, no success. I'm having dependencies problems when trying to install eUML2 studio from the update site. The instruction on the officail installation [page](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/installation/galileo/index.php) does not mention kepler at all.

Does someone was able to install eUML2 on Kepler? It was a great tool, if it has been discontinued its a real pity...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue so I had to change my mind. I now use an online UML tool

Comment: Which one? Can you provide me a reference?